# django CreateView doesn't show on ListView until rerun the server

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an object using CreateView

```
class PlayerCreate(CreateView):

    template_name = 'form.html'
    model = Player
    form_class = PlayerForm
    header = "Player"

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(PlayerCreate, self).get_context_data()
        context['header'] = self.header
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        valid = super(PlayerCreate, self).form_valid(form)
        if not self.request.user.is_staff or not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return HttpResponse("Only authorized user can edit or create")
        return valid
```

It works. However, when I jump into the ListView Part, I need to rerun

```
python manage.py runserver
```

to make the new item show on the list.

I want to make it work without rerun the server.
Thanks!

Below is my ListView code

```
class PlayerList(ListView):

    template_name = "list.html"
    header = 'Player'
    queryset = Player.objects.all().order_by("-timestamp")

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(PlayerList, self).get_context_data()
        context['header'] = self.header
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            return self.queryset
        else:
            return self.queryset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should only use `get_queryset()` not `queryset` in your `ListView`. `queryset` only runs the very first time your server starts while get_queryset() works every time a request is made, that's why you only see the new element in the ListView when you rerun `python manage.py runserver`.

An alternative solution could be:

```
def get_context_data(self):
    context = super(PlayerList, self).get_context_data()
    context['header'] = self.header
    context['players_list'] = Player.objects.all().order_by("-timestamp")
    return context
```